# data brick write xlsx in blob

Tags: python, azure, databricks, azure-databricks

trying to write a xlsx file in a blob storage

tryed thing like

```
df_MA.to_excel("https://ACCOUNTNAME.blob.core.windows.net/STORAGENAME/output/fold1/filename.xlsx")
```

but have error message

> No such file or directory:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mount the storage drive?

```
df.write.mode("overwrite").format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header","true").csv("/mnt/<mount-name>")
```

Comment: didnt want to do it but look like it's the only easy way

Comment: I think there are at least a couple ways to do it.  I believe that's the easiest way.

Comment: Yes mouting the blob is the easiest way. Look hard to write in blob if it's not mounted

Comment: This seems like a decent resource.
https://medium.com/@zifah/how-to-write-data-from-an-azure-databricks-notebook-to-an-azure-blob-storage-container-283bfdf23893

Comment: I can't actually test the code.  I don't have access to Databricks right now.  Anyway, that code looks right to me.